# invalid read syntax: "#"

Tags: server, clojure, compilation, pedestal

This is almost character for character what's on the pedestal api front page. I'm just trying to get everything verified to see that it works but it's not. What's wrong with my # here?[image]

EDIT: I'm an idiot. Emacs lets you do crazy things and I apparently was doing byte compiling of files which didn't like that very much. Other compile commands worked perfectly. I'm going to go do research on the difference between these various kinds.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the `#`.  There is something else wrong.  The errors/warnings show that the file is `core.clj`.  The namespace you have on line 3 is `web-app`.  What is on lines 1 and 2?

Comment: @dorab Nothing is on the line (new lines if you wanna be technical). I just popped them down to make the screen shot line up better. Changed namespace to core as well as core.clj to test out. Didn't do anything. Only change was that the first reference to free variable warning changed its name. Think maybe the issue is in the Leiningen project definition?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your edit would be better written as an Answer than as an edit to the question.